# iCloud connection via simulator possible with Advanced Data Protection?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm working on an app using CloudKit. To be able to test it in the simulator I used to log in with my iCloud account (I don't have a dedicated test device). This worked fine in the past until I activated advanced data protection for my iCloud account.

Since the I get the following error when the app tried to connect to my iCloud account in the simulator:

```
Unable to initialize without a valid iCloud account (CKAccountStatusTemporarilyUnavailable)
```

Is it possible to connect to an iCloud account with ADP activated for  that account? I first thought it would just take some time for Apple to adjust the simulator, but that was some month ago. So, did I miss something?